# Dynamics of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

How can we conclude that the transcendental entire functions need not have any fixed points?
For example consider $$f(z)=e^z+z,$$ why is it so?

Comment: In this case it's pretty clear that there is no fixed point because what you would have is $f(z) = z$ but then $f(z) = e^z + z$. Since $e^z \neq 0$, this equation does not have a fixed point.

Comment: thankyou for your response.may i clear about e^z not equal to zero does not have fixed points.

Comment: I got it thanks all.