# Does there exists a transcendental entire function having no fixed points?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exists a transcendental entire function having no fixed points?

I think yes, there exist a transcendental entire function having no fixed point...

As I take $ f(z) = e^z + 1$

Is it true or false?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450420/4890

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be $$ e^z + z $$
because $e^z + z = z$ implies...

Comment: im not getting  @will jagy,,,can u elaborate  more ???

Comment: @lomber: You want to check if $f(z) = e^z + z$ has a fixed point. Having a fixed point means that $z = f(z) = e^z + z$ which implies $e^z = 0$. Does it have a solution?

Comment: thanks a lots @Mehrdad